# Bootstrap Testimonial Carousel

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please take a look at next link:
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/ORaWE

What I want to do (and don't know how to achieve it) is to keep active avatar always in center. For example, if 3rd avatar is active, 3rd avatar will be in center (position 2), 1st avatar will be on position 3 and 2nd avatar will be on position 1.

Here is a small graphic demonstration:

(Imagin this as 3 avatars. Green one is currenlty active)
[image]

Anyone can help me or at least give me an idea or direction? :)

Comment: Is it certain that you will have only 3 avatar to display at a time or it can very. And if very then no of avatars will be odd only.

Comment: Dejan it is not easy to achieve with pure Bootstrap and I think no one will help you with that, when you didn't try anything to achieve that. I recommend you to use a plugin for this like slick carousel or owl carousel.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this behavior in bootstrap carousel you need to use javascript functionality of carousel instead of the inline `data-*` attributes.

Here is the working example of what you need -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var flag = false;
  $("#quote-carousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
    if (!flag) {
      var arr = $('ol.carousel-indicators > li');
      $($('ol.carousel-indicators')).append($('ol.carousel-indicators > li')[0]);
      $('.carousel-inner').append($('.carousel-inner > .item')[0]);
    } else {
      flag = false;
    }
  });

  $('#quote-carousel').carousel();

  $('.item-btn').click(function(obj) {
    flag = true;
    var arr = $('.item-btn');
    var index = arr.index(obj.currentTarget);
    var len = arr.length;
    var mid = Math.floor(len / 2);
    $('#quote-carousel').carousel(index);
    if (index < mid) {
      for (i = 0; i < (mid - index); i++) {
        $($('ol.carousel-indicators')).prepend($('.item-btn')[len - 1]);
        $('.carousel-inner').prepend($('.item')[len - 1]);
      }
    } else if (index > mid) {
      for (i = 0; i < (index - mid); i++) {
        $($('ol.carousel-indicators')).append($('.item-btn')[0]);
        $('.carousel-inner').append($('.item')[0]);
      }
    }
  });

  $(".left").click(function() {
    flag = true;
    var arr = $('ol.carousel-indicators > li');
    $($('ol.carousel-indicators')).prepend(arr[arr.length - 1]);
    arr = $('.carousel-inner > .item');
    $('.carousel-inner').prepend(arr[arr.length - 1]);
    $("#quote-carousel").carousel("prev");
  });
  $(".right").click(function() {
    flag = true;
    var arr = $('ol.carousel-indicators > li');
    $($('ol.carousel-indicators')).append(arr[0]);
    arr = $('.carousel-inner > .item');
    $('.carousel-inner').append(arr[0]);
    $("#quote-carousel").carousel("next");
  });
});
```

```css
/* Carousel */

#quote-carousel {
  padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  /* Control buttons  */
  /* Previous button  */
  /* Next button  */
  /* Changes the position of the indicators */
  /* Changes the color of the indicators */
}

#quote-carousel .carousel-control {
  background: none;
  color: #CACACA;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  text-shadow: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#quote-carousel .carousel-control.left {
  left: -60px;
}

#quote-carousel .carousel-control.right {
  right: -60px;
}

#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators {
  right: 50%;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: -19px;
}

#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 50px;
  opacity: 0.4;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators .active {
  background: #333333;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border-color: #f33;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.carousel-inner {
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.item blockquote {
  border-left: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.item blockquote p:before {
  content: "\f10d";
  font-family: 'Fontawesome';
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
      <div class="carousel slide" id="quote-carousel">
        <!-- Bottom Carousel Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li class="item-btn"><img class="img-responsive " src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brad_frost/128.jpg" alt="">
          </li>
          <li class="item-btn active"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/rssems/128.jpg" alt="">
          </li>
          <li class="item-btn"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adellecharles/128.jpg" alt="">
          </li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
        <div class="carousel-inner text-center">

          <!-- Quote 1 -->
          <div class="item">
            <blockquote>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. !</p>
                  <small>Someone famous</small>
                </div>
              </div>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
          <!-- Quote 2 -->
          <div class="item active">
            <blockquote>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
                  <small>Someone famous</small>
                </div>
              </div>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
          <!-- Quote 3 -->
          <div class="item">
            <blockquote>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. .</p>
                  <small>Someone famous</small>
                </div>
              </div>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Carousel Buttons Next/Prev -->
        <a href="#quote-carousel" class="left carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a href="#quote-carousel" class="right carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pepy9yLn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showAvatar(){
var no_of_avatars=3;

var data=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];

var start_index=10;

var msg='Start : ';

start_index=start_index-Math.floor(no_of_avatars/2)+data.length;

for(i=0;i<no_of_avatars;i++)
{
 $('#content-id').append('start_index+i : '+(start_index+i)+'<br>');
 msg+=','+data[((start_index+i)%data.length)];
}
  
$('#content-id').append(msg);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="showAvatar()">click to execute</button>
<div id="content-id">
</div>
```

This might help you. This is just the login with which you can have data in center but in case if your count of avatars are not odd then it will not generate perfect result though only small change will be required.